# Python etree rdf ¿cómo leer etiquetas?

Tags: python, xml

Muy buenas, 
tengo un fichero xml, y dentro en una etiqueta, hay código rdf que me gustaría recuperar.

El fichero es el siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<documento fecha_actualizacion="20191219105601">
  <metadatos>
    <identificador>BOE-A-2019-18092</identificador>
    <titulo>Orden EFP/1211/2019, de 11 de diciembre, por la que se establece el currículo del ciclo formativo de grado medio correspondiente al título de Técnico en Mantenimiento de embarcaciones de recreo.</titulo>
    <diario codigo="BOE">Boletín Oficial del Estado</diario>
    <diario_numero>303</diario_numero>
    <seccion>1</seccion>
    <subseccion/>
    <departamento codigo="9563">Ministerio de Educación y Formación Profesional</departamento>
    <rango codigo="1350">Orden</rango>
    <numero_oficial>EFP/1211/2019</numero_oficial>
    <fecha_disposicion>20191211</fecha_disposicion>
    <fecha_publicacion>20191218</fecha_publicacion>
    <fecha_vigencia>20191219</fecha_vigencia>
    <fecha_derogacion/>
    <url_eli>https://www.boe.es/eli/es/o/2019/12/11/efp1211</url_eli>
  </metadatos>
  <metadata-eli>
    <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:eli="http://data.europa.eu/eli/ontology#">
      <eli:LegalResource rdf:about="https://www.boe.es/eli/es/o/2019/12/11/efp1211">
        <eli:jurisdiction rdf:resource="http://www.elidata.es/mdr/authority/jurisdiction/1/es"/>
        <eli:type_document rdf:resource="http://www.elidata.es/mdr/authority/resource-type/1/o"/>
        <eli:id_local rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">BOE-A-2019-18092</eli:id_local>
        <eli:date_document rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2019-12-11</eli:date_document>
        <eli:number rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">efp1211</eli:number>
        <eli:has_member>
          <eli:LegalResource rdf:about="https://www.boe.es/eli/es/o/2019/12/11/efp1211/dof">
            <eli:jurisdiction rdf:resource="http://www.elidata.es/mdr/authority/jurisdiction/1/es"/>
            <eli:type_document rdf:resource="http://www.elidata.es/mdr/authority/resource-type/1/o"/>
            <eli:id_local rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">BOE-A-2019-18092</eli:id_local>
            <eli:date_document rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2019-12-11</eli:date_document>
            <eli:number rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">efp1211</eli:number>
            <eli:version rdf:resource="http://www.elidata.es/mdr/authority/version/dof"/>
            <eli:is_member_of rdf:resource="https://www.boe.es/eli/es/o/2019/12/11/efp1211"/>
            <eli:is_realized_by>
              <eli:LegalExpression rdf:about="https://www.boe.es/eli/es/o/2019/12/11/efp1211/dof/spa">
                <eli:language rdf:resource="http://www.elidata.es/mdr/authority/language/spa"/>
                <eli:title rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Orden EFP/1211/2019, de 11 de diciembre, por la que se establece el currículo del ciclo formativo de grado medio correspondiente al título de Técnico en Mantenimiento de embarcaciones de recreo.</eli:title>
                <eli:publisher rdf:resource="www.boe.es"/>
                <eli:date_publication rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#date">2019-12-18</eli:date_publication>
                <eli:realizes rdf:resource="https://www.boe.es/eli/es/o/2019/12/11/efp1211/dof"/>
                <eli:is_embodied_by>
                  <eli:Format rdf:about="https://www.boe.es/eli/es/o/2019/12/11/efp1211/dof/spa/epub">
                    <eli:format rdf:resource="http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/epub+zip"/>
                    <eli:embodies rdf:resource="https://www.boe.es/eli/es/o/2019/12/11/efp1211/dof/spa"/>
                  </eli:Format>
                </eli:is_embodied_by>
                <eli:is_embodied_by>
                  <eli:Format rdf:about="https://www.boe.es/eli/es/o/2019/12/11/efp1211/dof/spa/html">
                    <eli:format rdf:resource="http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/html"/>
                    <eli:embodies rdf:resource="https://www.boe.es/eli/es/o/2019/12/11/efp1211/dof/spa"/>
                  </eli:Format>
                </eli:is_embodied_by>
                <eli:is_embodied_by>
                  <eli:Format rdf:about="https://www.boe.es/eli/es/o/2019/12/11/efp1211/dof/spa/pdf">
                    <eli:format rdf:resource="http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/pdf"/>
                    <eli:embodies rdf:resource="https://www.boe.es/eli/es/o/2019/12/11/efp1211/dof/spa"/>
                  </eli:Format>
                </eli:is_embodied_by>
                <eli:is_embodied_by>
                  <eli:Format rdf:about="https://www.boe.es/eli/es/o/2019/12/11/efp1211/dof/spa/xml">
                    <eli:format rdf:resource="http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/xml"/>
                    <eli:embodies rdf:resource="https://www.boe.es/eli/es/o/2019/12/11/efp1211/dof/spa"/>
                  </eli:Format>
                </eli:is_embodied_by>
              </eli:LegalExpression>
            </eli:is_realized_by>
          </eli:LegalResource>
        </eli:has_member>
      </eli:LegalResource>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata-eli>
  <analisis/>
</documento>
```

Como veís es un xml normal y que dentro de una etiqueta tiene, descripción en rdf. Tras muchas pruebas no sé como leer ése código rdf.

Mi código lee primero las etiquetas normales, pero en la parte rdf no me recupera nada. He tratado de definir un namespace pero debo estar haciendolo mal.

```
from lxml import etree
    norma_xml = etree.parse(configuracion.tmplocal+fichero)
    elemento_raiz = norma_xml.getroot()
    aux = elemento_raiz.tag
    if aux != 'error':
        item = elemento_raiz.find("metadatos")
        codigoNorma = recuperar_valor_item(item.find('identificador'))
        titulo = recuperar_valor_item(item.find('titulo'))

        # El resto de campos lo voy a coger del ELI
        items = elemento_raiz.find("metadata-eli")
        namespaces = {'rdf': "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#", 'eli': "http://data.europa.eu/eli/ontology#"}
aux = items.findall("eli:LegalResource", namespaces)
```

¿Alguna idea de cómo leer?, por ejemplo:
Del eli:date_publication pillar 2019-12-18, o del

coger http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/pdf

Muchas gracias. Ando usando

Comment: ¡Buenas! Te dejo el link de la documentacion donde he sacado la informacion [aqui](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

Creo que solo necesitas hacer ```NombreEtiqueta.attrib``` y con eso te devuelve un diccionario con  todos sus atributos. Y de ahí es Python basico.

Comment: El tema está básicamente al llegar a la etiqueta que pone   <metadata-eli>, porque todas las de antes accedo correctamente y sin problemas, tanto a sus atributos si los tiene como a su contenido.
Pero la etiqueta <metadata-eli> tiene un contenido diferente, que entiendo que debo acceder por namespace, pero que no logro averiguar como. El contenido es rdf y no sé como navegar por ello recuperando las cosas.

Comment: Éste es el trozo problemático:

namespaces = {'rdf': "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#", 'eli': "http://data.europa.eu/eli/ontology#"}
        items = elemento_raiz.find("metadata-eli", namespaces)
        for item in items.findall("eli:has_member", namespaces):
            name = item.find('eli:id_local', namespaces)
He puesto que me recupere eli:id_local pr probar, pero no entra en el bucle. item está vacía.

Answer (score 1):

tras un buen rato lo acabo de solucionar. Os pongo como se hace para salvarle la vida a alguno que le paso lo mismo que  a mi:

```
namespaces = {'rdf': "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#", 'eli': "http://data.europa.eu/eli/ontology#"}
items = elemento_raiz.find("metadata-eli")
root_rdf = items.findall("rdf:RDF/eli:LegalResource/eli:id_local", namespaces)
cod = root_rdf[0].text
```

Con lo que he puesto recupero por ejemplo el valor de las etiquetas eli:id_local..valor /

Comment: ¡Gracias por postear tu solución!